# Cypress e2e test with stripe js

Tags: automation, automated-tests, stripe-payments, e2e-testing, cypress

I am writing an e2e test on cypress to a online store and after click the confirm purchase button it redirects to stripe page to input credit card and then redirects back to our store to show the receipt.

Does anyone one what should be the best way to perform this test? Should be by API?
 How to use stripe api to do the payment using cy.request in order to avoid redirecting to their page?

Thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately Stripe's front-end frameworks do not always play nicely with e2e tests. I suppose you could skip the checkout form for testing and then create a PaymentIntent or Subscription via the API using one of Stripe's evergreen test payment method tokens, https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You shouldn't be trying to test Stripe. See the commentary on this dude who wanted to test Paypal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667218/how-to-handle-elements-on-paypal-popup-with-cypress-io

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The first idea was to stub and create a "fake" payment but we have our own receipt and invoice generated after the transaction is made, so if we stub the response, we cannot check our invoice.

Comment: I am also trying to follow @duck's Idea to create paymentIntent via API but there is another complication. We are losing data due to the stored session.